# Macro after transfer data to another excel it should clear content in old/previous workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel macros. I have created this macro that transfer data to another excel file. However, after transferring the file it should clear the content from old sheet which I am not able to fix I get an error. Below is my code this will transfer data properly after that it stops and debugs at the below statement. Please help, after transferring data I want to clear content in old excel from where it has copied the data.
**Set ws = Workbooks("Path Old WorkBook").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").ClearContents**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim InvoiceNumber As String
Dim ForwarderCode As String
Dim Status As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Workbook

Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
InvoiceNumber = Range("A2")
Worksheets("SampleFile").Select
ForwarderCode = Range("B2")
Worksheets("SampleFile").Select
Status = Range("C2")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Path")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = InvoiceNumber
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = ForwarderCode
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = Status
End With

wb.Save

Set ws = Workbooks("Path Old WorkBook").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").ClearContents
Set ws = Workbooks("Path Old WorkBook").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").ClearContents
Set ws = Workbooks("Path Old WorkBook").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `Workbooks("Path Old WorkBook").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C2").ClearContents`. As you just want to clear the contents of the range, you don't need the `Set ws =` bit of the statement. `Set` is used in VBA to setup an object. For what you are trying to do, you don't need that. Also, you shouldn't use things like `Select` or `Activate`.. I hear you say why.. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) is why

Comment: I did now it is giving RunTime Error - 9 Subscript Out Of range

Comment: You must have the **old workbook** open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean for WS to refer to a Work*Book* or a Work*Sheet*?. Anyway, just backspace over those last 3 `Set ws =`  bits. So
`Workbooks("Path Old...").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").ClearContents`

Comment: I did now it is giving RunTime Error - 9
Subscript Out Of range

Comment: Ah! Take the quotes out from around Sheet2. Or use the name dispayed on the tab. Sheet# (where # is some integer or rather "Long", is how Excel identifies the Sheet _internally_. Maybe you named it "Sheet 2" *with a space?. Look in the Editor on the left. Both types of names will be listed under  +Microsoft Excel Objects. You may need to click the + to expand the list. If you don't see anything over there click the Project Explorer Icon or do Control-R.

Comment: @AkshayChari, see the 2nd topic in this [SODocumentation][1] link.  [1]:[https://sodocumentation.net/excel-vba/topic/2240/excel-vba-tips-and-tricks]